# VeeValidate - length for number input not not working if I add + in it

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I tried adding v-validate="'length:10'" for the number type input. It's working as expecting if I just add numbers, but I give + in it, it's accepting lots of numbers

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/woqp0ry5y7) to try. Try adding 1121212122+1212122 .

Answer (score 0):

Just update your input type to text and it will work fine.It will also display that values should be numeric if alphabets are typed.

As stated in [docs](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#length) the validation will work for input type text.

```
<input type="text" v-validate="'length:10'" v-model="number" />
```